# LINQ query not working - C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

The following LINQ query is trying to remove rows from DataTable if "Training" is either in the "Email" or "PreferredName' columns

```
  IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from rows in returnTable.AsEnumerable()
                               where !rows.Field<string>("Email").Contains("Training") || 
                               !rows.Field<string>("PreferredName").Contains("Training")
                               select rows;

  DataTable dt1 = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

It is not actually filter the rows from the `returnTable` variable.  What I am doing wrong?

Comment: what results are you getting?

Comment: You use AND in what you're trying to accomplish but an `||` in your code.

Comment: @ChrisLava - same results in `dt1` as in `returnTable`.  Seems like it just ignores the `where` clause

Comment: @NickGotch - I meant if the training is either in the email or preferred name column it should be remove from `datatable`.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Email" and "Preferred Name" column DO NOT contain "Training"

Use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from rows in returnTable.AsEnumerable()
    where !rows.Field<string>("Email").Contains("Training") &&
          !rows.Field<string>("PreferredName").Contains("Training")
    select rows;
```

Or thanks to [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), this is equivalent to:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from rows in returnTable.AsEnumerable()
    where !(rows.Field<string>("Email").Contains("Training") ||
            rows.Field<string>("PreferredName").Contains("Training"))
    select rows;
```

<sup>Note that both conditions are wrapped in parentheses, and the entire expression is negated.</sup>

Comment: The option using De Morgan's law worked to filter records.  Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out where **both** columns do not include "Training", then change the OR (||) to an And (&&).

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from rows in returnTable.AsEnumerable()
                           where !rows.Field<string>("Email").Contains("Training") && 
                           !rows.Field<string>("PreferredName").Contains("Training")
                           select rows;
```